# Entity Framework query syntax

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I having a trouble with a query

I need to take out the `SHIPMENT` from `GetAllOrderData` - the same place where you can find  `POD_DATE` and `RECEIVE_NAME`...but I get an error

> Error 1   The name 'x' does not exist in the current context

My code is:

```
public IEnumerable<ReportItemDTO> GetTaskProgress(DateTime targetDate)
{
   try
   {
      var startDate = targetDate.Date;
      var endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
      OrderDataRepository rep = new OrderDataRepository();

      var query = rep.GetAllOrderData()
                  .Where(x => x.POD_DATE >= startDate && x.POD_DATE <= endDate)
                  .GroupBy(o => o.User)
                  .Select(g => new ReportItemDTO
                    {
                      DriverId = g.Key.Id,
                      PdriverName = g.Key.Name,
                      OrderCount = g.Count(),
                      ReportedOrdersCount = g.Count(o => o.RECEIVE_NAME != null),
                      SHIPMENT = (x.SHIPMENT)
                    } );

      return query;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SHIPMENT = (x.SHIPMENT)
```

Well you are within a grouping when you try to make that assignment - there are *many* shipments in each grouping not just one - in fact all shipments for that particular user. Assuming you want a *collection* of them you could do:

```
Shipments = g.Select( x=> x.SHIPMENT)
```

**Edit:**

If you just want the first shipment for each user (somewhat illogical but fits your data model):

```
SHIPMENT = g.Select( x=> x.SHIPMENT).First()
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'

Comment: @user1021182: Your `Shipments` property in `ReportItemDTO` has to be of type `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: its a string 
        public string SHIPMENT { get; set; }

Comment: Did you read the answer? There are many shipments within that group - how do you want to get a single shipment out of it?

Comment: yes , but those are the same shipments...i mean each of the users has the same shipment code...

Comment: how can i print "all the "different" shipments?

Comment: I NEED TO GroupBy inside the select on g - can you pleas show me how

Comment: the query give results for each user 
it counts number of orders he has and number of orders he reported
the orders linked to SHIPMENT and i need to print all the shipments each user has

Comment: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: I can only repeat myself then: Your `Shipments` property in `ReportItemDTO` has to be of type `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: can you please show me how to set this - is that a change i need to do in the dto file? what about groupby inside the select g?